# Pandas Split Column into str and int columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently trying to split a column in my pandas dataframe into 2 columns, with 1 column as int and the other column as string. I understand that to be able to split a column into 2 columns, the following code can be used (where A is the column to be split into columns integer and string):

`df[['integer','string']] = df['A'].str.split(" ",expand=True,)`

However, the problems with my dataset is that there is no whitespace or "-" whatsoever between the integer and string as an indicator to split my column up. An example of my dataframe is as follows:

```
A     B 
3     abc
629S  def
84S   ghi  
S72   jkl
```

As seen, not all rows would have a letter and the int may not necessarily come before the letter.
My intended output is as follows:

```
integer      string      B
3            NaN         abc
629          S           def
84           S           ghi
72           S           jkl
```

Thank you so much for your help! Really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you need `str.extract` your use case seems quite simple so we can take advantage of `\D+` & `\d+`

`D+ matches any character that's not a digit (equal to [^0-9])`

`\d+ matches a digit (equal to [0-9])`

```
df['String'] = df['A'].str.extract('(\D+)') 

df['A'] = df['A'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)

print(df.rename(columns={'A' : 'Integer'}))


   Integer    B String
0        3  abc    NaN
1      629  def      S
2       84  ghi      S
3       72  jkl      S

print(df.dtypes)

Integer     int32
B          object
String     object
dtype: object
```

if you have `NaN` in your column :

```
d = """A     B 
3     abc
629S  def
84S   ghi  
Sss   jkl"""

from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d),sep='\s+')

df['A'] = df['A'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(float)

print(df)

       A    B
0    3.0  abc
1  629.0  def
2   84.0  ghi
3    NaN  jkl
```

or

```
df['A'] = pd.to_numeric(df['A'].str.extract('(\d+)')[0],errors='coerce')
print(df)

       A    B
0    3.0  abc
1  629.0  def
2   84.0  ghi
3    NaN  jkl
```

Comment: I tried to use this but I got this error: ```ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer``` for the line ```df['A'] = df['A'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)```.

Comment: @jenna_the_antenna you have `NaN` values then try `.astype(float)`  or wrap a `pd.to_numeric(df['A'],errors='coerce)` after extracting the ints.

Comment: when i tried ```.astype(float)``` I got ```NaN``` in the ```"integer"``` column for all rows that did not have a string, such as the first row in the example dataframe above. When I wrapped that after extracting the ints instead, I got the error ```SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal```.

Comment: @jenna you can't have it both ways, you can either have an integer/float column by removing any strings, or you can leave it as an object column.

Comment: i tried both separately and got the 2 errors respectively

Comment: It still doesn't work :( I still get ```NaN``` in the ```"integer"``` column for all rows that did not have a string for the 2nd method and for the 1st method I got the error ```TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not DataFrame```

Comment: can you add some data that mimics your example ? @jenna_the_antenna I'm unable to reproduce

Answer (score 1):

try this, using [Series.str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) & [Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

```
import re

replace = re.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)")

df['string'] = df['A'].str.extract(replace)
df['integer'] = df['A'].str.replace(replace, "")
```

---

```
  string integer
0    NaN       3
1      S     629
2      S      84
3      S      72
```

Comment: I got the error ```ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer``` for the line ```df['integer'] = df['A'].str.replace(replace, "").astype(int)```

Comment: I don't get the error anymore, however rows where the ```"string"``` column is ```NaN```, the ```"integer"``` column is also```NaN```. Is there any way to have the integer number such as have the number ```"3"``` in the ```"integer"``` column although the ```"string"``` column is ```NaN```

Comment: What do you mean by integer numbers

Comment: Theres no difference in the output